# Rvest to manipulate and extract value from HTML

Tags: html, css, r

Using R
I have getBrandlist in html as

```
 <div>\n  <span class="txt edittext">BrandName1 </span>\n  <span 
 class="cnt" data-val="116">(42)</span>\n</div>
 <div>\n  <span class="txt edittext">BrandName2 </span>\n  <span 
 class="cnt" data-val="116">(62)</span>\n</div> 
 ......
```

Now I have the number 62. I wish to extract BrandName2 that corresponds to this value. 
I tried using  `html_node(getBrandlist, css = '.cnt') %>% html_attr()` 
How do I go about this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
library(rvest)
doc <- read_html('<div>\n  <span class="txt edittext">BrandName1 </span>\n  <span 
 class="cnt" data-val="116">(42)</span>\n</div>
 <div>\n  <span class="txt edittext">BrandName2 </span>\n  <span 
 class="cnt" data-val="116">(62)</span>\n</div> ')
html_node(doc, xpath = "//span[text()='(62)']/preceding-sibling::span") %>% html_text
# [1] "BrandName2 "
```